# Translation from SQL to Datalog

Tags: sql, database, datalog

I am thinking of translating SQL queries to Datalog. Are there any tools that could completely do that? If there are, may I know what tools may I refer?

Comment: Do you mean datomic datalog or something else? May I suggest starting with an example that you'd like to translate, so we can think it through a bit?